# Command to verify a self sign cert is good to access the app or not

Tags: ssl, command, certificate, redhat, self-signed-certificate

Good day,

I have 2 app server, lets say App1 and App2.

I have a self sign cert in App2, I import this self sign cert into App1. But my App1 still not able to connect to App2 https url, its hitting the following error:

```
{
    "errorCode": "RSERR002",
    "message": "REST call failure with exception [sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]"
}
```

From App1, I am trying to use a command, to test the self sign cert, to verify whether I can use this cert to access to App2 https url or not.

If the command success to connect, then I may suspect that the way I import the self sign cert into App1 is wrong. With this, I can know more specific what is the issue.

Something like use command to load the cert, and then curl -i to the url?

I try google on this, but cant get the command, is such command exists? The app server is deployed in RED HAT Jboss.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, use curl command with cacert to pass in the certificate:

curl --cacert jboss.crt "https://sit.app1.com:8443/api/v10/main/init"